# ResizeArray Instance in property

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I try to convert C# code to F#

```
Items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item
    {
        Product = "",
        Category = "",
        Quantity = 1,
        Detail = "",
        Price = 220
    }
}
```

Follow code F#:

```
let items = ResizeArray<Item>()
items.Add(Item(
            Product = "", 
            Category = "", 
            Quantity = 1, 
            Detail = "", 
            Price = 220))
let body = 
    OrderRequest(
        Items = items)
```

How can I instantiate directly in the `Items` property? Without creating new variable and then make an `Add()`. Equal the first C# code.

I've tried it that way and it does not work:

```
let body = 
    OrderRequest(
        Items = ResizeArray<Item>(Item(
                                    Product = "", 
                                    Category = "",
                                    Quantity = 1,
                                    Detail = "",
                                    Price = 220)))
```

I get an error:

```
Error FS0193 Possible overhead: 'Generic.List (collection:
Generic.IEnumerable <Item>): ResizeArray <Item>'. 
Incompatible type restrictions. The 'Item' 
type is not compatible with
type 'Generic.IEnumerable <Item>'
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in F#, but it appears that you are passing an Item to a method that takes no parameters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried everything and nothing of success.

Comment: `ResizeArray` (also known as `System.Collections.Generic.List'1`) has a default constructor and two constructor overloads. The one you are after takes an argument of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1`. Try to pass your type `Item`as a sequence singleton, which can be concisely written as an F# list singleton, viz. `[ /*Item goes here*/ ]`.

Comment: @kaefer Thank you ! It worked

Answer (score 0):

If `Items` is of type `IEnumerable<Item>` (aka `Seq<Item>`), then you can write:

```
let body = 
    OrderRequest(
        Items =
            [ Item(
                Product = "", 
                Category = "", 
                Quantity = 1, 
                Detail = "", 
                Price = 220) ]
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `OrderRequest` constructor takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can do what @VasilyKirichenko suggests. Otherwise, if the `ResizeArray` is actually required, I suggest the following which is quite readable:

```
let body =
    seq { Item (Product = "",
                Category = "",
                Quantity = 1,
                Detail = "",
                Price = 220) }
    |> fun li -> ResizeArray<_> li
    |> fun ra -> OrderRequest (Items = ra)
```

Comment: Or merge the last 2 lines to `|> fun li -> OrderRequest(Items = ResizeArray li)`

Comment: Sure, you could merge these lines; I was going for clarity.